# Best JSF drag & drop designer?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, richfaces, wysiwyg, icefaces

I was very impressed by [this demo for the oracle ADF designer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/index.html) but it uses Jdeveloper and we dont like the ADF licensing.

Which of the more open licensed JSF libraries (if any) might give the closest/best drag & drop designer functionality using Eclipse?  We would consider richfaces/primefaces/icefaces etc and dont know which one(s) offer the best designer experience

Answer (score 2):

Check out JBoss Developer Studio.  It's tightly integrated with RichFaces:

https://www.jboss.org/products/jbds.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dragSupport.jsf The site has lots of example for richfaces. I tried to learn primefaces but switched to richfaces as it was bit easier to learn and ajax support is awesome.

Comment: I think that's not what the OP is looking for, but for a wysiwyg editor.